# Speechkit not working on iphone 6 (64 bit)

Tags: ios8, xcode6, text-to-speech, iphone-64bit

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Apple/Desktop/spechToTxt/SpeechKit.framework/SpeechKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Apple/Desktop/spechToTxt/SpeechKit.framework/SpeechKit (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SpeechKit", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_SKSearchRecognizerType", referenced from:
      -[ViewController saySomthingTap:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need the latest version of SpeechKit framework to support 64bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

To support Speech kit you need OS 10.0 and above then and then only you can able to run speechkit on iPhone.